# How do I add Calculated Columns to a table in the PowerPivot Data Model using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, object, powerpivot

I am aware that we can add/edit Measures to/in the Data Model from VBA using the ThisWorkbook.Model object. Is there a way to add Calculated Columns using VBA using the Model Object?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Why would you need that though? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Some times I have to create/update many columns. And I need an automated way to add it to the data model. Like have a table with Table-Name, Column-Name and Formula, and a macro that updates formulas or creates columns in the respective Table.